# how to add image in group in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

[image]In fabric js at the time of selecting the object i.e group i want to add cross-icon image on that group.Please help how it would be possible..

```
             <script>        
           canvas.on('object:selected', function (e) {
           var activeobject = e.target; //active element is group in which i want to add image
           var imgs = fabric.Image.fromURL('images/delete.png', function (oImg)  {

           oImg.scale(0.5).setFlipX(true);

                                });
            activeobject.push(imgs);//here .push is giving errpr that it is not a function
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem Where do you want to add your image.
To add an image on select you can follow this example:

```js
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({width: 100, height: 200, fill:'blue', top:10, left: 10});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({width: 100, height: 20, fill:'green', top:90, left: 80});
var group = new fabric.Group([rect, rect2]);
canvas.add(group);
canvas.on('object:selected', function (e) {
var obj = e.target;
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/256/Remove.png', function (oImg)  {
    oImg.scale(0.2);
    obj.addWithUpdate(oImg);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="400" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

The problem is image positioning.
Where do you want this image to appear?

Comment: Thank u so much.Problem is solved.I have one more issue can it solve

Comment: i checked all your issuem the problem is that the question are very bad made. Is hard to understand what you need and where are you failing.

Comment: this problem is solved..i have other issue i.e i  want to make each element of group active so that by clicking delete icon i could delete the whole group.

Comment: there is no straight support for group children event nor control customization. This require an heavy subclassing work.

Comment: ok.so is there any other way to delete whole group by clicking on delete icon

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to place the image permanently in a rectangle :

```
 fabric.Image.fromURL('UrlImage', (img) => {

  var img1 = img.set({
    left: rect.left,
    top: rect.top,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  });

  var group = new fabric.Group([rect, img1]);
  this.myCanvas.add(group);
  group.addWithUpdate();
});
```